# Directory permission with crontab

Tags: permissions, cron

I have a directory `my_website/public`, which I did `chmod 777` on. I set up a cronjob to delete all the files in `my_website/public/photos/*` But I got an email notification saying that `rm` does not have permission to remove the files in there. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which unix are you using? There has been a similar question for ubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

If I were you I would do the setup procedure again making sure that all command are done recursively i.e. `chmod -r` and `rm -r` since you might have chmodded the directory but not the files therein and not a subdirectory. If you're using ubuntu you might want to look into more specific resources how its cron is working.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The files in my `photos` directory are new every day. If I `chmod -r` today, will it also affect files coming into the directory tomorrow?